# Notification when build is fixed in devops

Tags: azure-devops

I can enable notifications for completed builds and failed builds but is there a way to
have notification for fixed builds?

That would mean builds that failed in the previous commit but does not fail in the most current one.

Comment: I checked your question and rickvdbosch's answer . it's a good way to follow his steps to try it first. If the solution is indeed helpful, you could mark it as a correct answer to let other one konw the solutions. If you have any questions and need help, we are happy to help you.

Comment: The answer, even if it is a helpful one, is only a start instruction where the remaining steps that leads to the goal is something I have to investigate myself. It is also an instruction of how to compensate for a missing key functionality that anyone would expect to already be there. What I will get from a service hook is an email that I compose myself, not one coming from the system, which is a bad thing. I appreciate the effort, but need more to not delete the question. If it contained links to useful videos, I wold consider accepting it, regardless of previously mentioned disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [About notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications) documentation, there are only notifications for completed builds and failed builds.

Looks like the closest we can get out of the box would be to create a [Service hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview) to notify a Service of a successful build.

[image: Create a service hook]

A solution closer to your needs would be to build your own API, call that from the Service hook and determine if the build has been fixed there.